# Wordpress plugin to auto execute php script on a specific time?

Tags: plugins

Is there a WordPress plugin that can auto execute php script on a specific time? Or an other way to do this?

At this moment I execute every 30 minutes (from 00:00 to 08:00) a php script with cpanel (Cronjobs). Is there some way to handle this in WordPress itself?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has its own built in Cron system. It isn't true Cron, it comes with its own caveats, but there's an excellent article [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/do-it-yourself-wordpress-scheduling-mastering-wp-cron/) which might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Your CPanel's cron will fire at your mentionned time without any issues. However, using WordPress' cron, it will fire only when someone visits your website.

Comment: Often, this is enough, or better, than a real cron. Why have your website doing things when nobody is looking at it?